# Another jQuery slider pause on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I've been looking around for a way to pause a slider I'm using, having been under the impression that there would be a simple .mouseenter() .mouseleave() function that I could incorporate (still fairly new to JS) and what I've seen seems to indicate that it just depends on how the code you're using is constructed.  I'm a bit overwhelmed at the moment so any help would be appreciated - my code is as follows:

```
        <div id="slideshow">
            <div class="vertical">
                <img src="" />
            </div>
            <div class="vertical">
                <img src="" />
            </div>
            <div class="vertical">
                <img src="" />
            </div>
        </div>

$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut()
.next()
.fadeIn(500)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  4500);
```

Comment: Do you use some library to your Slideshow ?

Comment: Hi Vincent! Nothing is being used in this slider other than defined images, jQuery, & CSS.

Comment: @Zeus77, the var in your suggested edit negates the end result I was after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm blaming my allergy attack yday for not getting this already - I was able to achieve what I wanted using a variation of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113069/jquery-slider-mouseenter-stop-mouseleave-start).

Cheers, SO! Adjusted code is as follows:

```
$(function(){
SliderStartStop();
$('#slideshow').hover(function(){clearInterval(sliderInt);},SliderStartStop);
});
function SliderStartStop(){
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
sliderInt = setInterval(function() { 
$('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut()
.next()
.fadeIn(500)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  4500);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a JSFiddle [right here](https://jsfiddle.net/j1zatyfq/2/)

Here's the JS code :

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
timer = setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
  .fadeOut()
  .next()
  .fadeIn(300)
  .end()
  .appendTo('#slideshow');
  },  1500);

$('#slideshow').hover(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
}, function(){
  timer();
});
```

I increase the speed of the animation just to see it works :)

Comment: That way, works, too, Vincent.  Thank you, sir, much obliged!
The only thing I noticed using this method is that all of the slides display simultaneously on the initial load.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to validate it ;)
Yeah, I removed your $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide(); when I was updating it, I will put it back.